# How can i get data from a subcollection in firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i m building an app using flutter and firebase as backend .
i m storring my data in a collection named 'Users' . every user has data and has a subcollection named 'Transactions' which are the transactions that he made .
i want to get these informations
Here is my DataBase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG0OF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDpFz.png)

```
class DatabaseService {
      final String uid;
      DatabaseService({this.uid});
      final CollectionReference usersCollection =
         FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

         List<Transaction1> TransactionsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          return Transaction1(
              uid: doc.data()['uid'],
              name: doc.data()['name'],
              description: doc.data()['description'],
              time: doc.data()['time'],
              argent: doc.data()['argent'],
              somme: doc.data()['somme'],
              deleted: doc.data()['deleted']);
              }).toList();
               }

      Stream<List<Transaction1>> get transactions{
        return  
    
usersCollection.doc(uid).collection('Transactions').snapshots().map(TransactionsListFromSnapshot);
       }
         }
```

and this is the flutter code

```
       body: StreamBuilder<List<Transaction1>>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: this.widget.uid).transactions,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData ? Stack(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print('hhhhh');
                return Transaction_Card(data: snapshot.data[index]);
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
                right: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _showMyDialog();
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ) :  Stack(
          children: [
            Text('Error'),
            Positioned(
                right: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _showMyDialog();
                  },
                ))
          ],
        );
      }),
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

I just did this yesterday. In my parent document I add an array in which I store the document id of the sub collection documents.

Then, in the repository I have the following function (projects are the main documents, areas are the sub collection documents

```dart
  @override
  Stream<List<Area>> areas(String projectId) {
    final CollectionReference areaCollection =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('projects').doc(projectId).collection('areas');

    return areaCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => Area.fromEntity(AreaEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

Then, I have used the [example of the bloc documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial?id=entities) with entities and models to transform the data.

For each (sub) collection I have a separate listener, so one for projects, and one for areas of my currently focussed project. If new areas arrive, I check whether I already know them (by id) or if I have to add a new area to the project.

```dart
for (var a in event.areas) {
      if (!areaPointer.containsKey(a.areaId)) { // add new area to list
        areaPointer[a.areaId] = project.areas.length;
        project.areas.add(a);
      }
      else                                      // update existing area
        project.areas[areaPointer[a.areaId]] = a;
    }
```

As you see, I also have an areaPointer which stores the relationship of area.id and index of project.areas[i]